# Regex for filtering

Tags: regex, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed Git parameter plugin in jenkins. There is an option for filtering branches from Git which needs a regex. So what I get in my branches dropdown is "origin/master". I need a regular expression where I need only word "master" and want to exclude "origin/" from all branches name.

Comment: A bit unclear in what environment (language) you want to achieve this. Assuming it's in the shell, then `grep` and/or `sed` could be the tools for the job.

Comment: i just need a regex

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's the thing with regexps - they don't quite "exclude" things, they only *match* (and that match can optionally be used for replace).

So you need to think more about the structure of the branch names and see what rule could describe it best.

`#[^/]+$#` (`#` is used as regexp delimiter here; if your system does not support arbitrary delimiters, the equivalent with slashes is `/[^\/]+$/` which is harder to read but works just the same) could be one option - it will match everything until the end of the string/line that does not contain slashes. This works as long as your branch names do not contain more slashes (e.g. `origin/feature/super-cool-stuff` would result in `super-cool-stuff` where one might actually expect `feature/super-cool-stuff`).

In other words there is no single correct answer to this without knowing what the branch naming rules are.

Comment: branches name are in format origin/branch_name .so i just need branch_name in my dropdown

Comment: Well, great then. In that case the regexp provided here should work well for you. Please don't forget to upvote/accept the answer that solves your problem.

Comment: / An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash (\)

Comment: That is very much vendor/implementation specific, most support arbitrary delimiters (I used `#`), but if yours doesn't, you can go with default (`/`) and escape the slash in the middle (see updated answer)

Comment: Also, it could be that your system does not require/expect delimiters at all - in which case remove the first and last characters, i.e. use only `[^\/]+$`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude `origin/` from the branch name, then you can try only searching for local branches:

```
git branch | grep master
```

Note that `git branch` with no options only searches local branches, `-r` searches only remote tracking branches, and `-a` searches everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`strip` option of format](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref#git-for-each-ref-refname):

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname:strip=3)' --shell --no-merged @ refs
# or
git branch -a --format='%(refname:strip=3)'
```

That way, `refs/remotes/origin` is not part of the output, and you can grep on your remote branches.

Regarding Jenkins and its branch filtering in the "Branch to Build", you can use:

```
^master
```

In order to isolate `master` only, not `origin/master`.
You could use a [negative lookahead as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37710101/6309) to exclude any branch with `origin`:

```
:^(?!.*origin/).*$
```